# Erasing comments for questionable reasons

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

Warning: Apparently one is not moderator after they reached 10K, unlike what SE privilege help pages declare, which led to the following incorrect assumption of the answer's author directly erasing comments to their answer. Regardless of that, I didn't vote to close this question because I still look for answers regarding comments asking for details being erased before I can read them (assuming the other comment erased was Emilio Pisanty's comment clarifying the chapter's name, which is uncertain), and/or before I get notified my concern was answered.

The following relates to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/505633/2451) written by Emilio Pisanty.

Originally, the said answer was referring to a chapter that did not exist in the most recent edition (3rd) of the book.

Naturally, I commented about it, asking for details about the edition Emilio Pisanty was referring to.

After a while, I noticed my comment was erased and Emilio Pisanty had updated their answer so as to clarify which chapter they were refering to.

My problem is the following one, in case this is not self-explanatory already: SE's answers contain plenty of comments asking for corrections and they were not erased after the answers were updated, let alone by someone else than the comment's author.

Secondly, while I receive a notification after a comment or an answer was posted, I was not notified of the edition of Emilio Pisanty's answer and it took me some time to figure what was going on.

So I am asking for a general statement about the right of moderators to erase comments on their own answers so as to make them look prettier, as the moderator also appears to be Emilio Pisanty.

Edit: I assumed one gained moderation privileges after reaching a specific reputation score, as the following page states:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: "Originally, the said answer was referring to a chapter that did not exist in the most recent edition (3rd) of the book" - frankly, that's pretty close to a downright malicious reading. The equivalent on my side is that you couldn't be bothered to do your basic due diligence and then pestered the answerer to do rather more work for you than could reasonably be expected. Sounds harsh? Then how about: "the answer referred to a chapter that I couldn't find, so I asked for clarification about what was meant"?

Comment: I don't see the problem here, you suggested a clarification, and the clarification was made. Therefore, your comment asking for such clarification is no longer needed, it adds nothing to the answer, the problem in question, or the solution.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, [Emilio Pisanty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/8563/emilio-pisanty) is not a [moderator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and therefore cannot delete comments by other users. 2 comments under [Emilio Pisanty's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/505633/2451) were flagged by users as *obsolete/no longer needed* and afterwards deleted by moderators.

Comment: What is the meaning of obsolete here? Does this category apply as soon as something is updated? Obviously erasing a comment is not an answer to that comment.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question update, SE privilege page states moderator privilege is obtained at 10K rep score, which Emilio Pisanty reached (their score is less but close to 20K). Why are they not moderator then?

Comment: 1. The flag reason reads: _It's no longer needed. This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post._ 2.  10k privileges are outlined [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). They don't include ability to delete comments by other users.

Comment: Also, out of technical curiosity, in the list of moderators, Chris has less than 10K. Does this mean the two are absolutely disconnected? i.e. one can be a moderator without any reputation score, and one is not moderator even though they gained infinitely high score.

Comment: Moderator status is not a reputation privilege. Moderators are elected by the Phys.SE community.

Comment: @Exocytosis Also see the [main privileges page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), which shows that several privileges are classed in the moderation category; you already have several of those privileges.